# How to translate "我爱的很野不会说谎等不等你都是一样" in English?

Tags: translation, meaning

I am trying to translate this sentence, but I don't think that I am going on the right way. I don't know how to reach the final.

Sentence: `我爱的很野不会说谎等不等你都是一样`

Pinyin: **wǒ ài de hěn yě búhuì shuōhuǎng děng bù děng nǐ dōu shì yíyàng**

My translation: **My very wild love don't lie, ...**

Is `等` meaning "and so on" or "wait"?

*This is a chorus of a music called 野 from 莫文蔚 (Karen Mok).*

Comment: Why is this downvoted? I see similar translations/meaning questions all the timde...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not one sentence:

我愛的很野 I'm a wild lover
不會說謊 I won't tell a lie
等不等你 Whether I wait for you or not
都是一樣 It will turn out the same

擅用美麗 I know how to use my looks
辣辣的闖 I knock them down I'm so hot
那怕愛到 even if I love till
一身傷   I'm covered with scars

愛要很野 Love's got to be wild 
帶點瘋狂 a little bit crazy
刺激著你 If it gets you all hot
別太緊張 Don't get too uptight

Yow.